# Convert date format from dd-MM-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd - in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a  column called `date` **(VARCHAR Type)** in my table which has dates like this

**date**

```
12-Mar-2019

4-Feb-2021

5-May-2021
```

I am created a new column called new_date **(Date Type)** and i want convert the dates in column `date` to look like the below in new_date

```
2019-03-12

2021-02-04

2021-05-05
```

**mysql syntax**

```
UPDATE `table`
SET new_date = CASE WHEN date REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'
                      THEN CAST(date AS DATE)
                      ELSE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d-%Y') END;
```

Comment: And you problem is? `'^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$'` does not match `[0-9]{1,2}-{A-Za-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}`

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if you had stored the date in a proper `date` column right from the start. The correct solution is to fix your broken data model first.

Comment: Do not use [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) (`date`) as column names.

Comment: Your sample data set doesn't appear to be properly representative of your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE test
SET new_date = CASE WHEN old_date REGEXP '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}'   -- test for YYYY-MM-DD
                    THEN old_date
                    WHEN old_date REGEXP '\\d{1,4}-\\w{3}-\\d{4}' -- test for DD-MMM-YYYY
                    THEN STR_TO_DATE(old_date, '%d-%b-%Y')
                    ELSE NULL                                     -- unknown format
                    END
WHERE new_date IS NULL     -- do not update existing values
;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5ce0332f4285567b8bd3a32ea611d84)

---

> this mysql code supports on only mysl 8.0 and not 5.7 – user14812075

For 5.7 - use class specification instead of `\d` and `\w` tokens:

```sql
UPDATE test
SET new_date = CASE WHEN old_date REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'
                    THEN old_date
                    WHEN old_date REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{1,4}-[[:alpha:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}'
                    THEN STR_TO_DATE(old_date, '%d-%b-%Y')
                    ELSE NULL
                    END
WHERE new_date IS NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=48e7bc739236f138f3756cb07a3186aa)

Comment: I think this mysql code supports on only mysl 8.0 and not 5.7

Comment: @user14812075 MySQL version is specified nowhere, so the solutoin for actual version is correct. PS. Updated...